# How to import larage csv file using cron job in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using **Laravel 8** and I want to **update billions of Products Prices**. I add this **code its work fine** but it is **not efficient** it add **load on server**.

```
 try {
        $priceCsvs = PriceCsv::whereStatus(PriceCsv::PENDING)->get();
        foreach ($priceCsvs as $price) {
            dump($price->name." is started");
            $csvData = fopen($price->file_url, 'r');
            $firstline = true;
            while (($data = fgetcsv($csvData, 555, ',')) !== false) {
                if (!$firstline && !empty($data)) {
                    dump($data);
                }
                $firstline = false;
            }
            fclose($csvData);
            dump($price->name." is End");
        }
   } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        dump($ex->getMessage());
   }
```

***Point is:*** Is there any way to **add sleep after 1000 entry** from **CSV file** or any other efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to schedule jobs then take a look at

[Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling)

Basically define some console (artisan) commands and then schedule them in the Console Kernel file. The scheduler is run with artisan and the recommendation is to run the command every minute (define a cron job). In the event that the kernel schedule item definition lines up with the minute that the 'php artisan schedule:work' command runs then your jobs will execute.